# Securing IP cameras on Aruba 1930

Tags: networking, security, ip-camera

I have purchased an Aruba 1930 POE switch to power IP cameras I plan to install around my home. I would like to configure a secure VLAN for these cameras in order to:

- Prevent them from communicating with the rest of my network (except the computer running the NVR)
- Prevent them from communicating over the internet

I suspect I need to use some combination of VLAN tagging (and possibly routing and ACLs), but being new to managed switches, I'm struggling for a solution.

What is the recommended way to accomplish my goals?